# Why do I get different results if I use first() vs last() on a QuerySet with the length of 1

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-annotate

while writing a testcase for a method I discovered that I get different results if I use my_queryset.first().my_annotated_value than when I use my_queryset.last().my_annotated_value although my_queryset.count() returns 1.

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
class ShopManager(models.Manager):

def get_best_matches(self, customer):

    shops = super(ShopManager, self).get_queryset().filter(employees__matches__customer=customer).annotate(max_match_percentage=Coalesce(Max('employees__matches__match_value'), 0)).order_by('-max_match_percentage')

    for shop in shops:
        shop.max_match_percentage = float(shop.max_match_percentage) * 100.0

    return shops
```

In the shell I run:

```
shops = Shop.objects.get_best_matches(customer=Customer_A)
shops.count() # returns 1

shops.first().max_match_percentage # returns 73.9843
shops.last().max_match_percentage # returns Decimal('0.739843')
```

I have different django apps for `shops`, `matches`, `employees` and `customers`.

I searched for hours and checked the implementation for first() and last() in the django docs. I could not find anything that explains this behavior.

Why are the values different, what exactly is happening? Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: Can you try running the `shops.first().max_match_percentage` and `shops.last().max_match_percentage` in reverse order. What are the results

Comment: @Tushortz I just tried that, the result is the same. `shop.last().max_match_percentage` still returns `Decimal('0.739843')` and `shop.first().max_match_percentage` still returns `73.9843`

Comment: You have a data consistency problem. The queryset is cloned again when calling `last` which does not run the `for` loop in the manager method, so what you're seeing is the current value in the DB. See Alasdair's answer.

Comment: Try to never evaluate the queryset in the manager. Managers are supposed to retrieve data from database, not alter them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `get_best_matches` method, you evaluate the queryset when you loop through it, and modify `shop.max_match_percentage` for each item in the queryset.

When you call `first()`, Django returns the first item in the evaluated queryset.

When you call `last()`, Django [attempts to return the first item of the *reversed* queryset](https://github.com/django/django/blob/8149bd00d8b8af816a683e5ecc0e204f344616f5/django/db/models/query.py#L556). This is a new queryset and causes a new database lookup. You have not set `shop.max_match_percentage` for this queryset, so you get the decimal from the database.

As you can see, it's probably not a good idea to loop through a queryset and modify it before returning it from a model manager method. If the queryset is cloned (e.g. by a further `filter()`, `order_by()` or in this case `last()`), then the changes are lost.

You should be able to do the multiplication by 100 inside the queryset, instead of looping through it:

```
shops = super(ShopManager, self).get_queryset().filter(employees__matches__customer=customer).annotate(max_match_percentage=Coalesce(Max('employees__matches__match_value'), 0)*100).order_by('-max_match_percentage')
```

If you really need to return a float instead of a decimal field, you can use [`Cast`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/database-functions/#cast).